# Why package routes does not load the controller class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add package in laravel `5.2.*`, but package routes returning error `Class FormController does not exist`.

**What i'm trying**

`Package Directory > packages\js\form\src`

**Package > Provider**

```
namespace Js\Form;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class FormServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
    }

    public function register()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
        $this->app->make('Js\Form\FormController');
    }
}
```

**Package > Controller**

```
namespace Js\Form;  
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

**Package > Composer**

```
{
    "name": "js/form",
    "description": "this is form",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "xyz",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {}
}
```

**Main Composer**

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Js\\Form\\": "packages/Js/Form/src"
        }
    }
```

**Package > Routes**

`Route::get('/contactus', 'FormController@index');`

In the config/app.php

`Js\Form\FormServiceProvider::class,`

I executed this command also `composer dump-autoload` then tried to open this url `http://localhost/project/public/index.php/contactus` but its showing following error.

`Class FormController does not exist`

Can anyone guide me where is issue that i can fix it. I would like to appreciate, if someone guide me. Thank You

Comment: I'm assuming the error comes from the router function. You just specify FormController so it will look in the default location for that (app/http/controllers) but that is not where the form controller is

Comment: @tam I agreed with you, issue is coming from route because i check it by adding wrong controller name. So how can i fix. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you try this command 
 php artisan config:clear  in CLI. Sometimes it happens it takes configuration from cache.

Comment: @RonakDattani I did, as you instructed but it still showing same error, when i refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
Route::get('/contactus', 'FormController@index');
```

The router by default looks for controllers relative to `App\Http\Controllers`, but that is not where your `FormController` is.

To fix this, you would need to specify where the `FormController` was *relative* to `App\Http\Controllers`, or by providing the *absolute* path.

For example, if your `FormController` was namespaced to `App\FormController`, you could write:

```
Route::get('/contactus', '\App\FormController@index');
```

So, in your case it would be:

```
Route::get('/contactus', '\Js\Form\FormController@index');
```

Comment: Wow Amazing, I followed the answer and its working. Thank you so much +1